# How can we form a graph from this problem?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, data-structures, binary-trees

[image]

So from the above diagram, we can move either right or down. So a binary tree is built that way. It's written `"If we had intermingled common nodes across different branches, we would have got a graph instead"` I am unable to visualize how a graph can be formed out of this. Will it be a graph with only 2 columns? Please help

Source: https://loveforprogramming.quora.com/Backtracking-Memoization-Dynamic-Programming

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! If the diagram comes from an online course or article, could you please add a URL in the question by using the edit button? If it comes from a book or a paper, a reference. Besides paying proper attribute to the original source, all that information also motivates and helps people answer your question faster and better.

Comment: @Apass.Jack Sorry bout that! Added the reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the visualization, then have a look at this
[image: Graph visualization of above tree]